# Modifying vlookup range or looping its range

Tags: excel, vba

Hope you're doing great, need help with below code that is supposed to match first column from 2 files then vlookup and copy paste the matched results. the problem is that i'm limited by vlookup range that only works for one column so i tried to make a loop to make it work on multiple number of cells as shown below but it's not working, any help or hints would be really welcomed, Thanks.
edit
the problem lies where `i`is used in the `funcStr` for the vlooukp table range and column's number, i need the range to be increased and column number to constinatly change to get the whole row copied instead.

```
Sub solution()

Dim oldRow As Integer
Dim newRow As Integer
Dim lrow_output As Integer
Dim WB_Input As Workbook
Dim WB_Output As Workbook
Dim WS_Input As Worksheet
Dim WS_Output As Worksheet
Dim funcStr As String
Dim i As Integer

Set WB_Input = Workbooks("File.xlsm")
Set WB_Output = Workbooks("output1.xlsx")

Set WS_Input = WB_Input.Worksheets("input")
Set WS_Output = WB_Output.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With WS_Output
    lrow_output = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With
For i = 2 To 6
With WS_Input
    funcStr = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & Cells(1, 1).Address(False, False) & "," & "'[" & WB_Input.Name & "]" & .Name & "'!" & Range(.Columns(1), .Columns(i)).Address & ",i,0),"""")"
End With
With WS_Output
    .Cells(1, i).Formula = funcStr
    .Cells(1, i).Copy
    Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lrow_output, i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    WS_Output.Calculate
    Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lrow_output, i)).Copy
    Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lrow_output, i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to simplify your question to the specific issue that's not working or strip out the code that you are confident is working correctly  (such as all the copying and pasting?). Hard to tell what's going on without more detail. Screenshots also help. [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: apologies for confusion, it's edited and i hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @DesTro what is the error code you are getting?  Have you tried `Index`/`Match` over `VLookup`?  It may very well simply the input/output.